# Rename duplicates accordingly in two Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have two Pandas DataFrames: **df_header** and **df_species**.

The first contain for each row the information about a vegetation plot (longitude, latitude, country, ...) and the second one contain for each row the information about a species (name, family, genus, ...). They both have a column named **RELEVE_NR**, which is the ID of the vegetation plot and indicates which species was found in which vegetation plot. Here is a small example of the two DataFrames to see what they look like, with a reduced number of column for simplification:

**df_header:**

| RELEVE_NR | Longitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 42.23 | 23.43 |
| 12346 | 36.85 | 39.25 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**df_species:**

| RELEVE_NR | Species | Family |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Agrostis stolonifera | Poaceae |
| 12345 | Paspalum vaginatum | Poaceae |
| 12345 | Scirpus lacustris | Cyperaceae |
| 12346 | Phragmites australis | Poaceae |
| ... | ... | ... |

As you can see, in a perfect world, I should have one different value in the column RELEVE_NR per row of **df_header**, but several time the same value in the column **RELEVE_NR** per row of **df_species** (we can imagine that each vegetation plot has a unique ID, but that each vegetation plot contains several observations of species).

However, it happens that we have several time the same value in the column **df_header** for several rows (I won't go into the details of why, but it can and it does happen). For these cases, here is what I have to do but can't find how:

- except for the first time it appears, rename the duplicated values of **RELEVE_NR** in **df_header** (with values that don't exist in the dataset obviously). For example, if we have three rows that have the value *12345* in the column **RELEVE_NR**, we could rename the second one *5001* and the second *5002* (if we are sure that no other vegetation plots have the IDs *5001* nor *5002*).
- duplicate each row that has this duplicated value in **df_species** the same number of time the value appeared. For example, if the vegetation plot *12345* had 10 values associated in the **df_species** DataFrame, we should duplicate each of them twice in order to have 30 values. We should let the first 10 with the ID *12345*, then put the number *5001* in the column **RELEVE_NR** for the following ten and finally the number *5002* for the last ten.

Quick example:
This **df_header:**

| RELEVE_NR | Longitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 42.23 | 23.43 |
| **12346** | 36.85 | 39.25 |
| **12346** | 36.85 | 39.25 |
| 12347 | 29.34 | 13.45 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Should become this **df_header** (we changed the value of the column **RELEVE_NR** of the second row having the value **12346** by a new number that isn't attributed to another row):

| RELEVE_NR | Longitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 42.23 | 23.43 |
| **12346** | 36.85 | 39.25 |
| **12348** | 36.85 | 39.25 |
| 12347 | 29.34 | 13.45 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And this associated **df_species**:

| RELEVE_NR | Species | Family |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Sorbus aucuparia | Rosaceae |
| **12346** | Agrostis stolonifera | Poaceae |
| **12346** | Paspalum vaginatum | Poaceae |
| **12346** | Scirpus lacustris | Cyperaceae |
| 12347 | Phragmites australis | Poaceae |
| 12347 | Paspalum vaginatum | Adoxaceae |
| ... | ... | ... |

Should become this **df_species** (we duplicated the 3 rows having the value *12346* in the column **RELEVE_NR** and we changed the values of the column **RELEVE_NR** for the duplicated rows to *12348*):

| RELEVE_NR | Species | Family |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Sorbus aucuparia | Rosaceae |
| **12346** | Agrostis stolonifera | Poaceae |
| **12346** | Paspalum vaginatum | Poaceae |
| **12346** | Scirpus lacustris | Cyperaceae |
| **12348** | Agrostis stolonifera | Poaceae |
| **12348** | Paspalum vaginatum | Poaceae |
| **12348** | Scirpus lacustris | Cyperaceae |
| 12347 | Phragmites australis | Poaceae |
| 12347 | Paspalum vaginatum | Adoxaceae |
| ... | ... | ... |

I hope it is clear. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'RELEVE_NR': [12345, 12346, 12346, 12347],
         'Longitude': [42.23, 36.85, 36.85, 29.34],
         'Latitude': [23.43, 39.25, 39.25, 13.45]}
data2 =  {'RELEVE_NR': [12345, 12346, 12346, 12346, 12347, 12347], 
          'Species': ['Sorbus aucuparia', 'Agrostis stolonifera', 'Paspalum vaginatum', 'Scirpus lacustris', 'Phragmites australis', 'Paspalum vaginatum'], 
          'Family': ['Rosaceae', 'Poaceae', 'Poaceae', 'Cyperaceae', 'Poaceae', 'Adoxaceae']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

For convenience, I will set df1 and df2.

**Code**

Step1

If you take the cumulative sum of the duplicated part and add it to the maximum value, the duplicated number will not be assigned.

```
cond1 = df1['RELEVE_NR'].duplicated()
s1 = df1['RELEVE_NR'].mask(cond1, cond1.cumsum().add(df1['RELEVE_NR'].max()))
df1.assign(RELEVE_NR=s1)
```

output:

```
RELEVE_NR   Longitude   Latitude
0   12345   42.23       23.43
1   12346   36.85       39.25
2   12348   36.85       39.25
3   12347   29.34       13.45
```

Step2

First, concatenate df1['RELEVE_NR'] and s1 horizontally to create a single DataFrame (df3). Then, merge df2 with df3. The remaining code is minor code to create an accurate output.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1['RELEVE_NR'], s1], axis=1).set_axis(['RELEVE_NR', 'key'], axis=1)
df2.merge(df3, how='left')\
   .assign(RELEVE_NR=lambda x: x.pop('key'))\
   .sort_values('RELEVE_NR', key=lambda x: x.map(pd.Series(s1.index, index=s1.values)))\
   .reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
RELEVE_NR   Species                 Family
0   12345   Sorbus aucuparia        Rosaceae
1   12346   Agrostis stolonifera    Poaceae
2   12346   Paspalum vaginatum      Poaceae
3   12346   Scirpus lacustris       Cyperaceae
4   12348   Agrostis stolonifera    Poaceae
5   12348   Paspalum vaginatum      Poaceae
6   12348   Scirpus lacustris       Cyperaceae
7   12347   Phragmites australis    Poaceae
8   12347   Paspalum vaginatum      Adoxaceae
```